# Where does keras store its data sets when using a docker container?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I was trying to run deep learning models using the cifar10 data set. When keras is installed on the system and one tries to use the data set, keras downloads it once in:

```
~/.keras/datasets/
```

I say that because I can ls that directory and I see:

```
$ ls
cifar-10-batches-py        cifar-10-batches-py.tar.gz cifar-100-python           cifar-100-python.tar.gz    mnist.pkl.gz
```

however when I install keras in a docker container `~/.keras` doesn't exist. I am sure its being saved somewhere because I can later load the data set when I log in to the docker image through a container with bash (with `docker run -it --rm tf_img bash`). However, I can't find here the files might be saved. Where are they saved?

Also once I find this location, I was planning to volume my local `~/.keras/` (or whatever computer I'm logged into) with the containers, so that the data sets don't have to be donwloaded 30 times every time I try to train some model.

---

First progress I found where `.keras` is using the `find -type d -name .keras` command in the container (its in `./root/.keras`). However, it seems that even though I volumed the folder correctly it downloads it anyway (even though I've went to the location `/root/.keras` in the container and see the stuff there as it is in my local computer). I did:

```
docker run -it --rm -v /Users/folder1:/Users/folder1 -v /Users/Pinocchio/.keras:/root/keras tf_cpu cifar10_cnn.py
```

and it still downloads the data set. Why?

Another thing that strikes me a super odd is that when I bash into the container it starts me inside of root which it has never done that before.

Comment: ok so after doing `find -type d -name .keras` it seems the location is `./root/.keras`. Now lets see what happens when I volume these.

Comment: typo in the -v it should be `.keras` not `keras`.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like I solved it. To find where `.keras` is in the container do once logged in to the container with bash ( as in `docker run -it --rm -v /local:/container image_name bash` for example) :

```
find -type d -name .keras
```

to discover that the location is

```
./root/.keras
```

Now just volume the location of the data set:

```
docker run -it --rm -v /Users/folder1:/Users/folder1 -v /Users/Pinocchio/.keras:/root/.keras tf_cpu cifar10_cnn.py
```

make sure to not have any typos, specially since its `.keras` and not `keras`.